# PHP explode and set to empty string the missing pieces

Tags: php, explode

What's the best way to accomplish the following.

I have strings in this format:

```
$s1 = "name1|type1"; //(pipe is the separator)
$s2 = "name2|type2";
$s3 = "name3"; //(in some of them type can be missing)
```

Let's assume `nameN` / `typeN` are strings and they can not contain a pipe.

Since I **need to exctract the name / type separetly**, I do:

```
$temp = explode('|', $s1);
$name = $temp[0];
$type = ( isset($temp[1]) ? $temp[1] : '' );
```

Is there an easier (smarter whatever faster) way to do this without having to do `isset($temp[1])` or `count($temp)`.

Thanks!

Comment: Don't think so, you'll get an exception/error if you try to access `[1]` without checking first.

Comment: This already looks like the most effective solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
list($name, $type) = explode('|', s1.'|');
```

Comment: Nice trick to handle the potential Notice, and an empty string rather than a null

Answer (score 4):

Note the order of arguments for explode()

```
list($name,$type) = explode( '|',$s1);
```

$type will be NULL for $s3, though it will give a **Notice**

Comment: will still have to check if type is null and assign ' ' to it if so though

Comment: if you do: @list($name,$type) = explode('|', $s1), the notice will be swallowed.  @Thomas - leverage php's untyped nature and allow php to type-juggle the null value based on its usage.

Comment: @Mark Baker: i updated the code in the question, thanks for telling me.

Comment: @Marco Using Stef's trick of appending a | before the explode guarantees no notice and an empty string in $type unless there is a genuine $type value

Comment: @Kevin Vaughan: +1 for your comment, but I did a test: it's true that with your solution `list` will not fire a Notice anymore when `$type` is missing, but `$type` would still be set to `NULL` and NOT to empty string, you can test with a simple `var_dump($type);`

Answer (score 3):

I'm a fan of [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) and [`array_shift()`](http://php.net/array_shift), which don't error out if the array they use is empty.

In your case, that would be:

```
$temp = explode('|', $s1);
$name = array_shift($temp);
// array_shift() will return null if the array is empty,
// so if you really want an empty string, you can string
// cast this call, as I have done:
$type = (string) array_shift($temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to do `isset` since $temp[1] will exist and content an empty value. This works fine for me:

```
$str = 'name|type';

// if theres nothing in 'type', then $type will be empty
list($name, $type) = explode('|', $str, 2);
echo "$name, $type";
```

Comment: I don't undertand the 2 limit you used in explode, what for?

Comment: you are right, but actually during development I use `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and when `$str='name'`, the call to `list($name, $type)` rises a PHP error `Notice: Undefined offset: 1`

Answer (score -1):

```
if(strstr($temp,"|"))
{
   $temp = explode($s1, '|');
   $name = $temp[0];
   $type = $temp[1];
}
else
{
   $name = $temp[0];
   //no type
}
```

Maybe?

Comment: Just a heads-up: If all you want to do is check if a needle-string is in a haystack-string, then you should use `strpos() !== false`, it's significantly faster than `strstr()`.